# What is the proper objective function?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I've got such function: [Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhNMY.png)

And the task is:

Please find a point among the values of the function f (x) that minimizes the square of the distance between the function and the point (2.5; 4.5).

So I defined the objective function:
[Objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AYgv.png)

I've tried to do some calculations, compute the derivative to find local minimum to find a range of X where probably I've got solution, but it doesn't help. IS there problem with my objective function? In Wolfram Aplha it is said that there is no solution in the domain of real numbers, only in the domain of complex numbers (but it's impossible - in my opinion)

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)=4-x^{3/2}$, you should consider the function$$F(x)=\left(x-\frac52\right)^2+\left(f(x)-\frac92\right)^2=x^3+x^2+x^{3/2}-5 x+\frac{13}{2}.$$Then$$F'(x)=3 x^2+2 x+\frac32\sqrt x-5.$$But here you have a problem: the equation $F'(x)=0$ has no “nice” solutions. It has one and only one real solution, which is $x_0\approx0.817997$. So, the point that your after is $\bigl(x_0,F(x_0)\bigr)$.

Comment: But can you show how did you solve this F'(x) that you know it's like 0.817997

Comment: I used Mathematica to do it.